# Jest: Spy on object method?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, spy

I need to spy on `Date.toISOString()` and return a value.

`const spy = jest.spyOn(global, Date);`
spies on Date global

`const spy = jest.spyOn(global, 'get', Date);`
spies on Date global get

But how do you spy on the object methods? And return a value?

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(global.Date, 'toISOString').mockImplementation(() => {
        return new Date().now()
      })
```

`Cannot spy the toISOString property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(global.Date.toISOString).mockImplementation(() => {
        return new Date().now()
      })
```

`Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given`

Comment: No. That returns `Cannot spy the toISOString property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

Comment: There's no such thing as `Date.toISOString()`.

Comment: Yes, it's an instance method. But how to stub that?

Answer (score 3):

Figured the solution:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(global.Date.prototype, 'toISOString').mockImplementation(() => {
        return '123123123'
      })
```