# Jest mockImplementation(Promise.resolve) returns undefined when spying on an object called from another class (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, async-await, jestjs

I'm having trouble getting a Jest mockImplementation to return data with Promise.resolve() in a particular context.

In my Node.js code, I have a structure that puts all the API-calling code in one class (Api), and all the business logic in another (Repo). When you instantiate Repo, it creates an instance of the Api class for itself: `this.api = new Api()`

I'm trying to test a function in the Repo level, and mocking the Api call so we don't actually make any queries during testing.

```
  const data = { postId: 3, id: 3, name: 'Bob Your Uncle' };
  beforeEach(() => {
    getSpy = jest.spyOn(repo.api, 'getPage').mockImplementation(() => {
      Promise.resolve(data);
    });
  });
```

When I execute the function, `expect(getSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` returns true, but the value it returns is "undefined" rather than the expected promise resolved.

When I do a real-life run of the code, it works just fine, but the test fails. I suspect the problem may have to do with the fact that the code I'm testing is calling a second user-written class, by I'm not sure. I found this question [Jest: Spy on object method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65151813/jest-spy-on-object-method) that seems related, but their solution (adding .prototype to the spyOn argument) didn't help me -- they were working with a native JS object rather than a user-defined one, which seems different enough to explain the difference.

Here is the full `describe` block:

```
describe('Repo: fetchRand', () => {
  const data = { postId: 3, id: 3, name: 'Bob Your Uncle' };
  beforeEach(() => {
    getSpy = jest.spyOn(repo.api, 'getPage').mockImplementation(() => {
      Promise.resolve(data);
    });
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  it('should fetch call this.api.getPage once', async () => {
    let res = await repo.fetchRand();
    expect(getSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
  it('should return an object with a postId and an name', async () => {
    let res = await repo.fetchRand();
    expect(res).toHaveProperty('postId');
    expect(res).toHaveProperty('name');
  });
});
```

and the module being tested:

```
const Api = require('./Api');

module.exports = class Repository {
  constructor() {
    this.api = new Api();
  }
  async fetchRand() {
    let id = this.getRandomInt(5);
    let res = await this.api.getPage(id);
    return res;
  }
  getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
  }
};
```

And a link to [a GitHub repo with the full code](https://github.com/kenirwin/jest-mock-problem-StackOverflow) -- run `npm test -- Repo.test.js` to replicate the problem. (This is not my real project, just the simplest full code to replicate the basic nature of the problem.)

Comment: Check the syntax again, it doesn't return a promise. There's `mockResolvedValue` to make the intention more clear.

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask -- I don't understand why it's not returning a promise, but `mockResolvedValue` worked for me. I'm new to Jest and I'm finding new ways to mess up every day ;)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is specific to JavaScript arrow syntax and not Jest. `getPage` spy doesn't return a promise, so it returns `undefined`.

It should be either use implied return with no brackets:

```
.mockImplementation(() => (
  Promise.resolve(data);
));
```

Or explicit return:

```
.mockImplementation(() => {
  return Promise.resolve(data);
});
```

A shortcut for spy implementation that returns a promise is:

```
.mockResolvedValue(data);
```

Answer (score 3):

The comment from Estus Flask led me to the write answer. Nothing to do with the class-within-a-class business at all, just using the mock wrong I guess.

This change worked:

```
getSpy = jest.spyOn(repo.api, 'getPage').mockResolvedValue(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a mock function declared and mocked outside of the test function body, whereas `jest` configuration had

`resetMocks: true`

option.